# Error while using make on vxl in Opengaze installation

Tags: git, ubuntu, makefile

I'm trying to use make to build vxl(http://sourceforge.net/p/vxl/wiki/Git-Download-VXL/), but when the process gets to 99% an error appears:

`[ 99%] Built target breg3d
    [ 99%] Built target breg3d_pro
    [ 99%] Built target boxm2_class
    [ 99%] Built target boxm2_volm
    Linking CXX shared library ../../../../../lib/libboxm2_vecf.so
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboxm2_ocl
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboxm2_ocl_algo
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbocl
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[2]: *** [lib/libboxm2_vecf.so] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [contrib/brl/bseg/boxm2/vecf/CMakeFiles/boxm2_vecf.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [all] Error 2`

I already did a search on google and I did not found nothing on the subject.
How can I solve this problem?
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means it cannot find the libraries and headers for OpenCL.

If you are sure you have OpenCL headers and libraries, e.g. /usr/include/CL, specify it during cmake with the flags.

`-DOPENCL_INCLUDE_PATH=/path/to/CL -DOPENCL_LIBRARIES=/dir/of/libOpenCL.so -DOPENCL_LIBRARIES=/path/contains/libOpenCL.so`

Then try to compile it again.
If you don't have OpenCL headers, run the following command (Ubuntu):

`sudo apt-get install opencl-headers`

I am sure there are similar packages if you are using other platforms.